# Number converter only works on second try

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a simple console application that just gives a phone number and writes it by letters, but the problem is that you need to enter a number first and it starts working after the first number.

```
print("---Give numbers by letters---"+"\n")
#number=input("Phone: ")
number_convertor={
"0":"oh",
"1":"one",
"2":"two",
"3":"three",
"4":"four",
"5":"five",
"6":"six",
"7":"seven",
"8":"eight",
"9":"nine"
}
while True:
    result=""
    number=input("Phone: ")
    for ch in number:
        result+=number_convertor.get(ch,"!")+" "
        print(result)
```

Output:

```
---Give numbers by letters---

Phone: 0
Phone: 0
oh
Phone: 0
oh
Phone: 0
oh
Phone:
```

and when I remove the 2th line, is prints multiple times!

```
---Give numbers by letters---

Phone: 021
oh
oh two
oh two one
Phone:
```

Comment: remove the second line and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-You were prompting the user to enter a number 2 times

2- The final print doesn't have to be within the for loop, but outside it.

Try this, and you don't need the while loop.

```
print("---Give numbers by letters---"+"\n")
number_convertor={
"0":"oh",
"1":"one",
"2":"two",
"3":"three",
"4":"four",
"5":"five",
"6":"six",
"7":"seven",
"8":"eight",
"9":"nine"
}
result=""
number=input("Phone: ")
for ch in number:
    result+=number_convertor.get(ch,"!")+" "
print(result)
```

Comment: @Arian No problem, though, if you want to do it indefinitely, just put back the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs; you discard the result from the first `input`, and you repeatedly print `result` while producing it.

There is no need to collect anything into `result` anyway if you just want to print one number at a time.

The first `print` probably makes more sense to perform after the initialization of the dictionary, together with the other I/O. I also propose a simplification of the initialization.

```
numbers = "oh one two three four five" \
    " six seven eight nine ten".split()

print("---Give numbers by letters---")

while True:
    sep = ""
    number = input("Phone: ")
    for ch in number:
        print("%s%s" % (sep, numbers[int(ch)]), end=sep)
        sep = " "
    print()
```